# How to deal with large raw image re-renders causing lag in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, blob, web-performance

I am modifying the background position of a background image that a user just uploaded (and so is a raw Data URI) using CSS but the re-rendering starts to lag if the image is >1mb.

The issue is not present for smaller images.

Is there anyway of dealing with this short of trying to optimize renders? I already am not re-rendering unless the background position changes by at least 1% (i.e. the change was 1% or greater between re-renders).

The issue is not present with the same image when I host it and then load the image from a URL.

You can see this issue in a small [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-ishizaka-6ydi3?file=/src/App.js) that I made. Using the image in the default URL works well, but taking the file and uploading it makes it very laggy.

Could I somehow cache the data? It would seem like it is lagging because the raw data is not cached whereas the image is being cached.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with the logic a bit and changed `styles.backgroundPositionY` to direct style manipulation by ref element. I don't see any big improvements. Uploaded image was indeed lagging while moving it where the default one was nimble.

```js
const imageDivRef = useRef(null);

  const onUpload = e => {
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = onLoadEvent => {
        const dataUri = onLoadEvent.target.result;
        let image = new Image() // try to cache that
        image.src = dataUri;
        image.onload = () => {
          resolve(dataUri);
        }
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])

  }).then(dataUri => {
    updateBackgroundImage(dataUri)
  })
};

  const onPan = e => {
    const y = position.y;
    const delta = (e.deltaY / CONTAINER_HEIGHT) * -100;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      imageDivRef.current.style.backgroundPositionY = `${Math.min(
        Math.max(y + delta, 0),
        100)}%`
    })

  };

  const onPanEnd = e => {
    const y = position.y;
    const delta = (e.deltaY / CONTAINER_HEIGHT) * -100;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    imageDivRef.current.style.backgroundPositionY = `${Math.min(
      Math.max(y + delta, 0),
      100)}%`
    })
  };
```

There is also one crazy idea. Ditch the `backgroundPositionY`, make wrapper div with overflow hidden and fixed size, put inside it img element, and manipulate it with `transform: translateY(unit)` property. I wonder if that can be quicker...

Answer (score -1):

Next js has a image optimization future not a basic solution but...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).